# ActiveMerchant - SagePay - testing in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, opayo, activemerchant

I'm working on a project where I need to change how their payment processing works. I'm trying to process transactions in development and have test details from their site, however keep getting

```
The IP address of the server sending the transaction does not match the valid IP address ranges listed in the Simulator.
The IP address Simulator sees for your server is ***.***.***.***. You can add this IP in the Accounts section of Simulator if you wish. - See more at: http://localhost:5000/portal/expeditions/redland-green-2018/17606/payment-schedule/add-payment#sthash.JKA3S8lz.dpuf
```

Is there any way of me disabling this check when in development mode? I can't find any sagepay documentation for Rails and can't find any option for it in active merchant..

Thanks in advance

Comment: this could help https://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/tea-commerce/tea-commerce-support/25693-SagePay-integration

Comment: What simulator are you using? Is it the sandbox integration or the old .asp one?